# How to use master detail concept in Android using Eclipse with sqlite

Tags: android, gridview, android-sqlite

How to use gridview in android? And how to fetch data from sqlite in android and display it in gridview?
Can I implement master detail concept in android 4.0 for Samsung Galaxy Note? And please give me all information about master detail concept in Android.

Answer (score 0):

as a start, it would be nice if you could tell us if you tried anything ;)

Here is a start for the [Sqlite interaction](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) and the [gridview](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)